# Sierra WWAN Kernel Module Acting Strangely

Tags: wireless, kernel, modprobe, wwan

So a few days ago I installed Zorin OS (basically, Ubuntu with a Windows-like desktop environment) on my grandmother's computer to save it from the slowness of Windows 7.

Now, since she uses an AT&T USB Modem (Sierra AirCard 313U) I have to load the `sierra` and `sierra_net` modules (since they're not loaded by default). So, I made this file in `/etc/modprobe.d/sierra-wwan.conf`:

```
#load Sierra kernel modules
install sierra /sbin/modprobe sierra
install sierra_net /sbin/modprobe sierra_net
```

Though, for some reason, it won't load the modules. After some hair pulling, I got desperate enough to just load the modules from an `init.d` script (yeah, I know you're supposed to use `modprobe.d` **specifically** for kernel modules, but I was desperate) and it contained this:

```
#/etc/init.d/sierra-wwan

#load Sierra kernel modules
#yeah, yeah, I know it's /etc/modprobe.d for kernel modules, don't judge me
modprobe sierra
modprobe sierra_net
```

Now, at least the modules load (as verified with `lsmod | grep sierra`), but the module won't actually *do* anything (i.e. recognize the modem, connect to AT&T, etc...) unless I login to my account, and reload the module with `sudo modprobe -r sierra sierra_net; sudo modprobe sierra sierra_net`, logout, and log my grandmother in again.

I have tried loading, then reloading using the `init.d` script (and with a `modprobe.d` conf), but it only works if I do it manually.